# PowerBI - Filtros con tarjeta

Tags: powerbi

estoy comenzando a crear informes en power BI, pero siguiendo un curso que tiene una versión anterior a la que estoy trabajando, me encuentro con la siguiente problemática en filtros.

El informe trata de diferenciar los pagos efectuados a mujeres y a hombres.
Por lo que al finalizar quiero crear dos tarjetas, en una sumando los pagos efectuados al personal femenino y en otra los pagos efectuados al personal masculino. El problema es que una tarjeta me  afecta a todo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El reporte original es el siguiente ( nota que la tarjeta, cambia al total)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que puedo notar que estas opciones no estan en la version que tengo, mas que nada la casilla que dice select all:

Mi objetivo es que en la primer tarjeta se sume los pagos al personal femenino, y en el segundo los pagos al personal masculino, manteniendo a ambos sexos en todos los gráficos.